# Is it considered bad form to execute javascript returned by an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm modifying an existing web application that features the ability to administrate users who are able to log into the system. When modifying a user's details via a dialog, update data is sent to the server via AJAX. A few lines of javascript to then update the current page to reflect these changes is returned with the intention of being executed. This strikes me as poor form - isn't executing remotely acquired JS dangerous?

If I were to modify this, I would have the AJAX call that sends the updated information then call another function that gets the latest data from the server via AJAX (or just refresh the page, if I am feeling lazy). Is there any advantage (mainly security, but from an architectural perspective as well) to making this change, or am I being anal?

Comment: If you're executing JS coming from your own application and it's not user submitted data there's no security risk. It's only dangerous if you can't trust what the code contains.

Comment: @Juhana: That's only true if the entire site is on HTTPS, and even then you may be at risk of DNS or route poisoning + users' general willingness to ignore security errors.

Comment: i dont really understand the problem. if you posting the user details anyway by ajax, isnt it clear text? so its allready a security breach? open for packet sniffing etc? now, if you allready send the data with an ajax call, isnt it simpler to return a json response with the updated details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming we're talking about eval used on non-json.

People will tell you all sorts of things, most of it has some basis in reality. I'd say one reason that is really understandable: it will make the code a nightmare to maintain and it will be very hard to trace bugs.

There are security concerns, a lot of people like to jump on the "javascript is the clients problem" bandwagon. I say if it comes from your site, it's your problem too.

In the end, there is no good reason I can think of to eval javascript from the server. Pass data from the server, and write the javascript on the client-side to react to that data.

Comment: If we're assuming eval used on non-json, I fully agree. But as you say, AJAX should return data, so it should be JSON. So what's your opinion if we assume it is JSON being returned?

Answer (score 3):

All JS executed by the browser is remotely acquired.

The server that returned the JS/JSON via AJAX is the same server that returned the HTML that did the AJAX call in the first place.

It if's possible to do something bad, it can be done whether you `eval` the result of the AJAX call or not.

Comment: I *tend* to think this is the correct answer, although I'm open to be convinced otherwise.

Comment: @Krule, The browser simply returns the fetched document to the JS code that requested it. It doesn't execute it if it's JS or JSON. Think of it as `wget` for JS.

Comment: @Krule, I did test. `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {}` does nothing at all, whereas `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { eval(xmlhttp.responseText); }` works. Verified Content-Type too.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't see the issue. Sure, people say things such as "It allows code execution client-side" however if the potential attacker is able to affect that, then that's your problem - not the ability to modify the code.

Seriously, I think you have far more pressing concerns than that. I'd personally spend that 10 minutes or so reviewing your code and looking for flaws instead of working on an alternative to eval(). I think it'll improve your security a fair bit more.

Mike Samuel mentions MITM. I don't see why. If you're susceptible to a MITM attack then chances are that code can be injected straight into the initial HTML page (again, sure, slightly higher risk but is it really worth worrying about? Your choice.)

Comment: Is it slightly higher risk? IMHO it's the same risk factor. Just remember to escape user entered string (if there is one) you return with your AJAX loaded javascript.

Comment: Maybe by "initial HTTP page" you meant "initial HTML page"?

Answer (score 1):

If a trusted developer wrote **all** of it and you protect it the way you do the rest of your HTML page, then no.

But even if it is JavaScript written by trusted developers, if it is served over HTTP, then an attacker can modify it in-flight because HTTP over free wireless is often susceptible to [MITM](http://www.excitingip.com/1125/honeypot-man-in-the-middle-attack-wireless-intrusion-prevention/).

This can be used to effectively install a keylogger in the current browser window to steal user passwords, redirect them to phishing pages, etc.

The attack might work like this:

1. Web page does a GET to `http://example.com/foo.js`.
2. Attacker modifies `foo.js` mid-flight to add JavaScript that does `window.addEventListener("keypress", /* a keylogger that sends all keys to evil.com cross domain by image loading tricks */)`
3. Browser loads modified JavaScript.
4. User enters a password in an `<input type=password>`.
5. Evil wins.

Since HTTPS (assuming no mixed content) is not susceptible to MITM, it is not vulnerable to this attack.

Comment: But if a Man in the Middle attack is happening, why would an attacker wait for this kind of Ajax thing to come along instead of manipulating the page straight away?

Comment: I think this a bit picky, personally. MITM attacks in this sense are somewhat rare however, ignoring that, the attacker has many more chances within which to attack. This might be something to worry about if you're working for a bank and if cross-domain AJAX was permitted then it'd be a totally different story, but personally I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Comment: @Muu, MITM attacks are not that rare.  Users re-use passwords, so even if you're not a bank you should keep passwords safe.

Comment: @Pekka, Yes, if the HTML page is served via HTTP, then the attacker could work there.  But if the AJAX call is mixed-content, e.g. via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) or a library doing cross-domain messaging to emulate CORS, then it becomes a problem.  Some large sites have mixed-content problems because they serve "static" content on separate origins via HTTP and use these tricks to do mixed-content kinds of data fetches.

Comment: @Mike fair enough, that sounds feasible

Comment: @Mike Samuel, This MITM JS could just as easily have been returned in the HTML that made the AJAX call in the first place, so it's not a reason to not `eval` the JS or JSON returned by AJAX. (It's a reason to use HTTPS for both, but that wasn't the question.)

Comment: @ikegami, I addressed this in my response to Pekka.

Comment: @Mike Samuel, Not at all. You only showed problems with using code sent over the clear. Like I said, you haven't shown any problem with using `eval` on what AJAX returns.

Comment: @ikegami, `eval(x)` grants a lot of authority to whomever controls `x`, so if the HTML is protected from tampering by HTTPS, and the JS is not, then you should not `eval` the JS because you cannot be sure that it comes from a trusted source.

Comment: By your logic, you should never execute JS at all, because it might have come from a non-trusted source, because HTTP might have been used instead of HTTPS. NONSENSE!

Comment: @Mike: In reality, they are relatively rare when compared to far more frequent attacks on web applications. I'd argue that it's worth spending that extra time looking for other flaws, e.g. unsanitised inputs, etc.

Comment: @Muu, Ok, you spend your extra time looking for unsanitized inputs in the OP, and I'll address the question asked.

Comment: @Mike: I did that too, I'm just putting things into perspective that's all - we've both put forward our views.

Answer (score 0):

Sort answer: Yes

Long answer: You should just send data for both security reasons and to keep your implementations separate.

Improperly sanitized user-submitted content or advertisements could inject code and get it run.  Granted, this would have to be a targeted attack, but hey maybe you're working for a startup that's going to be the next Google or a forum system that's going to be the next vBulliten.  Even if you have 10 users, security holes are still holes and are still bad for you and your users.  Also, bad security advice left lying around SO will lead others to make bad decisions.

Do you really want to have to make sure the code you generate on the fly and send to the client is correct in all possible cases?  What if someone else works on just one half of the system?  Are they going to know every variable name to avoid stomping on?  Just sending data is the best way to keep a 'small' change in your client/server communication from breaking everything in ways that aren't obvious and will take forever to debug.

Comment: What security reasons are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to just call another function after you send the data update because you could then display information that isn't true if an update fails.  At least with the current model, your service can tailor the javascript based on whether or not the update was successful.  You may want to consider having the service just return a true/false and have the call back function handle the updating of the UI.